# Is there an easy way to convert a gedit plugin from the gnome2 version to the gnome3 version?

Tags: linux, gnome, gedit

I'd like to transfer my plugins to the new gedit in Gnome 3 (coming from Gnome 2 Gedit), but they don't all work.

I've changed their location from ~/,gnome2/gedit to ~/.local/share/gedit, and I've renamed all from *.gedit-plugin to *.plugin and I've changed the header in those files from [Gedit Plugin] to [Plugin]. I can see them now in the plugins tabs of the preferences, but enabling them results in an error.

Are there any simple fixes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually not that hard if you use python. You already converted the .plugin files. In the python files, this is a typical diff:

```
-import gtk
-import gedit
-import gobject
-import pango
+from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject, Gedit

.......

-class PluginName(gedit.Plugin):
+class PluginName(GObject.Object, Gedit.WindowActivatable):
+    window = GObject.property(type=Gedit.Window)
+
     def __init__(self):
-        gedit.Plugin.__init__(self)
+        GObject.Object.__init__(self)
         self._instances = {}

-    def activate(self, window):
-        self._instances[window] = PluginNameWindowHelper(self, window)
+    def do_activate(self):
+        self._instances[self.window] = PluginNameWindowHelper(self, self.window)
+
+    def do_deactivate(self):
+        self._instances[self.window].deactivate()
+        del self._instances[self.window]

-    def deactivate(self, window):
-        self._instances[window].deactivate()
-        del self._instances[window]
+    def do_update_state(self):
+        self._instances[self.window].update_ui()

-    def update_ui(self, window):
-        self._instances[window].update_ui()

.......

-        self._action_group = gtk.ActionGroup("PluginNameActions")
+        self._action_group = Gtk.ActionGroup("PluginNameActions")

.......

-             line = document.get_text(line_start, line_end)
+             line = document.get_text(line_start, line_end, False)
```

I converted 6 plugins some time ago, and these were the only changes I needed.

Comment: Nice. The plugin I'm working with seems a little tricky though: http://pastie.org/3725963... And that's only one file!

Comment: You mostly need to use GObject Instrospection and adjust the methods as it was suggested by Jens.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try. By the way jens or @gpoo, can you guys send me your converted plugins to see if any of them happen to be ones that I wanted to convert? My gmail: trusktr. Thanks!